# Why are bootstrap multiselect options disabled by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I do not understand why these simple multiselect options are not clickable.

**EDIT**

The first multiselect on the test-site below is the one in question.  I have tested using Chrome and Firefox.

**EDIT-2**

I am also using angularjs and think there may be a conflict somewhere. I am in the process of testing this hypothesis out.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>

<label for="work-type" class="fixed50">Type:</label>
<select id="work-type" name="work-type[]" multiple >
    <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
    <option value="non-fiction">Non-Fiction</option>        
</select>
```

The only javascript referense:

**JS**

```
$("#work-type").multiselect();
```

Here is a link to my  [test-site](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/enablers).

Comment: What exactly is disabled on that demo? Issue isn't clear. The green selects work for me. If those ones aren't the problem then provide a proper [mcve] without extra UI nd provide steps to replicate problems

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that. It is the very first multiselect. What browser are you using> I tested with Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to introduce a js file and a css file.
See details：
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/